# Linking characters from one data.frame to other datasets

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with two columns. The first column contains various specific times during a day. The second column contains the animal behavior (behavior period) that I observed at each specific time:

```
Time; Behavior

10:20; feeding

10:25; feeding

10:30; resting
...
```

For each of those behavior periods I have an additional dataset (TimeSeries) which contains data about the actual animal movement (output from a movement sensor). Each TimeSeries has about 100 rows:

```
Time; Var1; Var2

10:20:01; 1345; 5232

10:20:02; 1423; 5271

...
```

Now I would like to link each TimeSeries with the behavior from the first dataset. So, that R knows that "feeding" is related to the TimeSeries of 10:20 and 10:25 and that "resting" is related to the TimeSeries of 10:30 and so on.

Afterwards I want to use this "knowledge" to calculate mean and sd from each TimeSeries. So I will have all the means and sd's from all TimeSeries for each behavior.

Comment: Please provide usable (R code) complete reproducible examples, with also the expected output of the solution you expect.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303283/how-to-do-vlookup-and-fill-down-like-in-excel-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether your times are currently characters, factors, POSIXct, variables, etc.  So you should first convert them (possibly in a new column) to a numeric variable, something like the number of seconds since midnight.  Functions like `strptime`, `difftime`, and `as.numeric` may help.

Add a column to the first data frame that is just `1:nrow(firstdf)`.  Then add a column to the second dataframe that is computed by the `findInterval` function:

```
seconddf$newcol <- findInterval( seconddf$seconds, firstdf$seconds )
```

Now you can merge the 2 data frames on the new columns and the finer grained times will be associated with the activity from the most recent time.