# R data frame reshape, restructure, and/or merge

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, reshape

I'm trying to reshape and "expand" data.frame based on the values contained in the data.frame.  Below is the structure of the data frame that I am starting with:

**Starting structure:**

```
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Delivery.Location    : chr  "Henry" "Henry" "Henry" "Henry" ...
 $ Price                : num  2.97 2.96 2.91 2.85 2.89 ...
 $ Trade.Date           : Date, format: "2012-01-03" "2012-01-04" "2012-01-05" "2012-01-06" ...
 $ Delivery.Start.Date  : Date, format: "2012-01-04" "2012-01-05" "2012-01-06" "2012-01-07" ...
 $ Delivery.End.Date    : Date, format: "2012-01-04" "2012-01-05" "2012-01-06" "2012-01-09" ...
```

The market where this price data comes from is called the "next day market" since the physical delivery of natural gas is *typically* the day after the natural gas was traded (i.e. `Trade.Date` above).   I emphasize *typically* because there are exceptions that occur on weekends and holidays in which case the delivery period might be for multiple day period (i.e. 2-3 days).  However, the data structure is provided with variables that explicitly state the `Delivery.Start.Date` and `Delivery.End.Date`.

I'm trying to restructure the data.frame in the following way to produce some time series charts and do additional analysis:

**Desired structure:**

```
$ Delivery.Location
$ Trade.Date
$ Delivery.Date    <<<-- How do I create this variable? 
$ Price
```

How do I create the `Delivery.Date` variable based on both the existing `Delivery.Start.Date` and `Delivery.End.Date` variables?

In other words, the data from the 2012-01-06 Trade.Date looks like this:

```
Delivery Location   Price      Trade.Date      Delivery.Start.Date     Delivery.End.Date     
Henry               2.851322    2012-01-06     2012-01-07              2012-01-09
```

I want to somehow "fill in" Delivery.Location & Price for **2012-01-08** to get something like this:

```
Delivery Location     Price      Trade.Date      Delivery.Date
Henry                 2.851322    2012-01-06     2012-01-07   
Henry                 2.851322    2012-01-06     2012-01-08   <--new record "filled in"
Henry                 2.851322    2012-01-06     2012-01-09
```

Below is a subset example of my data.frame:

```
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## sample data
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
df <- structure(list(Delivery.Location = c("Henry", "Henry", "Henry", "Henry", "Henry", "Henry", "Henry", "Henry", "Henry"), Price = c(2.96539814293754, 2.95907652120467, 2.9064360152398, 2.85132233314846, 2.89036418816388,2.9655845029802, 2.80773394495413, 2.70207160426346, 2.67173237617745),  Trade.Date = structure(c(15342, 15343, 15344, 15345, 15348, 15349, 15350, 15351, 15352), class = "Date"), Delivery.Start.Date = structure(c(15343, 15344, 15345, 15346, 15349, 15350, 15351, 15352, 15353), class = "Date"),  Delivery.End.Date = structure(c(15343, 15344, 15345, 15348, 15349, 15350, 15351, 15352, 15356), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Delivery.Location", "Price", "Trade.Date", "Delivery.Start.Date", "Delivery.End.Date"), row.names = c(35L, 150L, 263L, 377L, 493L, 607L, 724L, 838L, 955L), class = "data.frame")

str(df)

##--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
## create sequence of Delivery.Dates to potentially use
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rng <- range(c(range(df$Delivery.Start.Date), range(df$Delivery.End.Date)))
Delivery.Date <- seq(rng[1], rng[2], by=1)
```

Any assistance or general direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please be specific what you want?

Comment: @Metrics:  I have edited my question to hopefully make it more clear.  My apologies for not being more specific from the onset.

Comment: NP; do you want the difference between start and end date for delivery?

Comment: @metrix. No don't want difference just want the price to be the same for all dates between the start date and end date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ddply` from the `plyr` package

```
library(plyr)
ddply(
      df,
      c("Delivery.Location","Trade.Date"),
      function(trade)
      data.frame(
      trade,
      Delivery.Date=seq(
          from=trade$Delivery.Start.Date,
          to=trade$Delivery.End.Date,
          by="day")
      )
 )
```

Of course, you would still have to implement the logic regarding the weekends, holidays, etc.

I have also assumed that `Delivery.Location` and `Trade.Date` are sufficient to identify a single trade.

Answer (score 1):

Is this okay?

```
library(plyr)   



lookuptable<-df[,2:3]

Trade.Date<-df[,4]
filluptable1<-as.data.frame(Trade.Date)
Trade.Date<-df[,5]
filluptable2<-as.data.frame(Trade.Date)

myfillstart<- join(filluptable1, lookuptable, by = "Trade.Date")
myfillstart<- rename(myfillstart, c(Trade.Date="Delivery.Start.Date"))
myfillstart<- rename(myfillstart, c(Price="Price.Start.Date"))
myfillend<- join(filluptable2, lookuptable, by = "Trade.Date")
myfillend<- rename(myfillend, c(Trade.Date="Delivery.End.Date"))
myfillend<- rename(myfillend, c(Price="Price.End.Date"))
finaldf<-cbind(df[,1:3],myfillstart,myfillend)



finaldf
    Delivery.Location    Price Trade.Date Delivery.Start.Date Price.Start.Date Delivery.End.Date Price.End.Date
35              Henry 2.965398 2012-01-03          2012-01-04         2.959077        2012-01-04       2.959077
150             Henry 2.959077 2012-01-04          2012-01-05         2.906436        2012-01-05       2.906436
263             Henry 2.906436 2012-01-05          2012-01-06         2.851322        2012-01-06       2.851322
377             Henry 2.851322 2012-01-06          2012-01-07               NA        2012-01-09       2.890364
493             Henry 2.890364 2012-01-09          2012-01-10         2.965585        2012-01-10       2.965585
607             Henry 2.965585 2012-01-10          2012-01-11         2.807734        2012-01-11       2.807734
724             Henry 2.807734 2012-01-11          2012-01-12         2.702072        2012-01-12       2.702072
838             Henry 2.702072 2012-01-12          2012-01-13         2.671732        2012-01-13       2.671732
955             Henry 2.671732 2012-01-13          2012-01-14               NA        2012-01-17             NA
```

**Note:** Since you have the same location, I didn't look up for the location. But, you can do the same. The code looks a little bit messy. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303283/how-to-do-vlookup-and-fill-down-like-in-excel-in-r) are the alternatives which you can also go through.