# Is there a lookup function in R like vlookup in excel?

Tags: r, excel, lookup, qdap

i want to know if there is a lookup() function in R package 'qdap'. I installed it and tried to use it, but throws up an error "could not find function "lookup".

```
for(k in 1:nrow(mtmModFrame)){
          mtmModFrame$mtm[k]<- lookup(uiqFrame$DATE[k], mtmFrame$DATE, mtmFrame$stcockMtm) }    
    print(mtmModFrame)
```

thanks in advance. amit.

Comment: Maybe `data.table` or `merge` would help?

Comment: There are other `R` methods equivalent to Excel's VLOOKUP, see here: [How to do vlookup and fill down (like in excel) in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15303283/1036500)

Comment: Try checking here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303283/how-to-do-vlookup-and-fill-down-like-in-excel-in-r

Comment: You've installed the package, but did you load it (using `library(qdap)`)?

Comment: I think you need the development version: see the directions [HERE](https://github.com/trinker/qdap) to download the dev version.

Comment: Many here closed this question because it was about `lookup` hash tables.  That is not what this is about.  It's about a specific problem in a specific package and should not have been closed though the title does not match the content of the question.