# replace loop with an *pply alternative

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to speedup my code by replacing some lookup loops with tapply ([How to do vlookup and fill down (like in Excel) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303283/how-to-do-vlookup-and-fill-down-like-in-excel-in-r)) and I stumbled upon this code piece:

```
DF<-data.frame(id=c(rep("A", 5),rep("B", 7),rep("C", 9)), series=NA, chi=c(letters[1:5], LETTERS[6:12], letters[13:21]))
for (i in unique(DF$id)){
  DF$series[ DF$id==i ]<-1:length(DF$id[ DF$id==i ])
}
DF
```

Is it possible to replace this with an `*apply` family function? Or any other way to speed it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try `ave`:

```
DF$series <- ave(DF$id, DF$id, FUN = seq_along)
```

For larger data sets, `dplyr` is faster though.

```
library(dplyr)

fun_ave <- function(df) transform(df, series = ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along))

fun_dp <- function(df) df %.%
                 group_by(id) %.%
                 mutate(
                   series = seq_along(id))

df <- data.frame(id= sample(letters[1:3], 100000, replace = TRUE))

microbenchmark(fun_ave(df))
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min       lq   median      uq      max neval
# fun_ave(df) 38.59112 39.40802 50.77921 51.2844 128.6791   100


microbenchmark(fun_dp(df))
# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# fun_dp(df) 4.977035 5.034244 5.060663 5.265173 17.16018   100
```

Answer (score 2):

Could also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, series_new := 1:.N, by = id]
```

and using `tapply`

```
DF$series_new  <- unlist(tapply(DF$id, DF$id, function(x) 1:length(x)))
```

Extending @Henrik's comparison above both `data.table` and `dplyr` are quite a bit faster for large data sets.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(id= sample(letters[1:3], 100000, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = F)
dt <- data.table(df)

fun_orig <- function(df){
  for (i in unique(df$id)){
    df$series[df$id==i]<-1:length(df$id[df$id==i])
  }}

fun_tapply  <- function(df){
  df$series <- unlist(tapply(df$id, df$id, function(x) 1:length(x)))
}

fun_ave <- function(df){
  transform(df, series = ave(df$id, df$id, FUN = seq_along))
}

fun_dp <- function(df){
  df %.%
  group_by(id) %.%
  mutate(
    series = seq_along(id))
}

fun_dt <- function(dt) dt[, 1:.N, by = id] 

microbenchmark(fun_dt(dt), times = 1000)
#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr      min       lq   median      uq      max neval
# fun_dt(dt) 2.473253 2.597031 2.771771 3.76307 40.59909  1000

microbenchmark(fun_dp(df), times = 1000)
#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# fun_dp(df) 2.71375 2.786829 2.914569 3.081609 40.48445  1000

microbenchmark(fun_orig(df), times = 1000)
#Unit: milliseconds
#         expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# fun_orig(df) 30.65534 31.93449 32.72991 33.88885 75.13967  1000

microbenchmark(fun_tapply(df), times = 1000)
#Unit: milliseconds
#           expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# fun_tapply(df) 56.67636 61.72207 66.37193 102.4189 124.6661  1000

microbenchmark(fun_ave(df), times = 1000)
#Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min      lq   median       uq      max neval
# fun_ave(df) 97.36992 103.161 107.5007 139.1362 157.9464  1000
```