# Add a column to a data frame based on values of another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, nested-loops

I have a data frame with temperatures from summer 2013. I would like to map the temperatures geographically using their latitude and longitude based on this [example](http://jeffreybreen.WordPress.com/2011/01/05/cran-zipcode/). 
I have a dataset with the temperatures and zip codes and I would like to add a column with the appropriate lat and long to my original data frame.

I wrote a nested loop that works but is terribly inefficient:

```
for (i in 1:length(Summer2013$zipcode)) {
  for (j in 1:length(zipcode$zip)) {
    col[i] <- if (Summer2013$zipcode[i] == zipcode$zip[j]) {
      zipcode$longitude[j] 
    } else {0}
  }
}
```

(so far I thought I'd just try doing the long and when I figured out something better, I was going to do the lat as well)

I know that R is able to perform loops using column assignments but I was afraid of not getting an expected result so wanted to err on the side of caution.

Comment: You may want `ifelse`, but the code you're showing here will overwrite values in `col` repeatedly, so it's not clear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I do realize that there is a problem but without an else clause, the code failed before.

Comment: I am trying to add two columns to my data frame - one with long based on zipcode and one with lat based on zipcode. This would be equivalent to a vlookup in excel.

Comment: I guess you would gain speed from something like `zipcode[c("latitude", "longitude")][match(Summer2013$zipcode, zipcode$zip), ]`

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303283/how-to-do-vlookup-and-fill-down-like-in-excel-in-r/15307710#15307710

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 1):

you want to merge the datasets:

```
merge(Summer2013, zipcode, by.x="zipcode", by.y="zip", all.x=TRUE)
```

this is a left join and will return NA for zipcodes it can't find in the `zipcode` data frame.